# Create file on FTP request

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, sublimetext2

Is it possible to have my server create a file on the fly when it is requested via FTP?

For example, my programming IDE (in my case Sublime Text 2) tries to download a file via FTP (SFTP) called "content_123.htm" from the server. content_123.htm doesn't exist when the request is made, but I want the server to automatically create the file when it is requested, putting the contents of a page in my database with an id of "123" into that file.

Has anyone ever done anything like that?

Comment: You could configure a rewrite rule that turns it into a call to a download script, and the script can create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: How it access that file http/ftp? Which one?

Comment: Apologies both, I meant via FTP. Do rewrite rules affect FTP?

Comment: I have seen an event listener that uploads a saved file via ssh (i.e., on local save is the trigger), but I have never seen a remote file created by trying to download something that doesn't exist at that remote location.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps there's a Sublime extension to download files over HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but after some research I found a Sublime Package called [SublimeHttpRequester](https://github.com/braindamageinc/SublimeHttpRequester) which can be installed via the package installer.

You have to paste the URL you want to download first, select it, then get the package to download it, but it uses HTTP so .htaccess/PHP can be used to put together a page that isn't already there to download.

I hope that an easier method will come along, but for now that should help anyone searching!